# Deleting this inappropriate answer, please

Tags: support

Is it possible to delete this answer by any moderator or anyone who has the privilage to do so?

Link to the Question :: [What can I do to make sure that I have the energy to work on my game while working full-time?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17916/what-can-i-do-to-make-sure-that-i-have-the-energy-to-work-on-my-game-while-worki)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's what the "flag" button is for.